# How to get name of any application from its resources in English locale?

Tags: android, locale

I can get the name of the application using this code:

```
PackageInfo appInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
String      label   = appInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
```

It gives names of application in default locale. But I need in English.

I also tried:

```
int    id    = context.getResources().getIdentifier("app_name","string",packageName);
String label = context.getString(id);
```

But `id == 0` always

Now my question is:
How to get the name of the application from resources `res/values/strings.xml - app_name`, knowing the name of the package?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the names of installed apps:

```
String appName = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
```

The reason that the `app_name` method is not working, is that this is a default, but is not always what is used.

Comment: It gives names in locale which is set on device. For example: default language on my device is French, and names of some apps will be in French. But I need in English

Comment: When you create apps, do you add an app name for multiple locales? Nobody does.... This is not something you can retrieve, the app name is the app name.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with another way. [How to change locale of another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764867/how-to-change-locale-of-another-app/19766578#19766578)  Specially thanks to Matt Clark!

Comment: This is the right answer. The accepted answer gets the label that is locale based. This answer can get the app name in the specified locale.